# bind() picks zero port

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, posix

I am trying to write some socket app and got a problem. I want OS to pick random free port number for my address. 
But I receive port number = 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addrLen;
int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd == -1) {
    ThreadError("Failed to create data channel socket");
}
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = 0; // pick random free port
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = srvAddr; // = inet_addr(127.0.0.1)
if (bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    ThreadError("Failed to bind data channel");
}
if (getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrLen) == -1) {
    ThreadError("getsockname() failed");
}
if (listen(fd, 1) == -1) {
    ThreadError("Failed to set socket to listen mode");
}
// addr.sin_port == 0
```

Comment: @AhmedMasud The quotation you provided is explicitly about a socket which hasn't been bound at all. There is nothing there that says you have to do it that way, contrary to what you alleged, and there is also nothing there that says you can't bind() to a zero port, which is what you also alleged. You can also bind() to a zero *address,* i.e. INADDR_ANY.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `addrlen = sizeof addr` before you call `getsockname`.

The size is an in-out parameter. You specify the size of the buffer you're providing, and the function tells you how much of the buffer it used by modifying the size.